# IJCAD2019上で.NETのプリンター出力後にIJCADを終了するとエラーになる。

Tags: .net, ijcad

IJCAD2019上で.NETを使用してプリンター出力しIJCADを終了するとエラーが出力される。
PlotReactorManagerを使用しない場合には問題なく終了する。
プリンター出力をしないでPlotReactorManagerのイベントの登録と解除だけの場合も問題ない。
Visual Studioのデバック上で動作させている場合にはエラーとならない。
エラーが出ないようにする方法はないでしょうか？
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
namespace PlotTest
{
    public partial class Plotting : Form
    {
        public int PlotReactorErrChk;
        public PlotReactorManager plotReactorMng = null;
        public string PlotTestFileName = @"C:\temp\test.dwg";// 印刷ファイル
        public Plotting()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            plotReactorMng = new PlotReactorManager();
            PlotEventsRegister();// イベントの登録

　　　　　　// プリンターデバイス群をコンボボックスに代入

            GcadDocument Gdoc = (GcadDocument)GrxCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.AcadDocument;
            var styleNames = Gdoc.ActiveLayout.GetPlotDeviceNames();
            foreach( string PlotDevice in styleNames)
            {
                PlotListBox.Items.Add(PlotDevice);
            }

        }

        private void Plot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                using (Document Doc = GrxCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.DocumentManager.Open(PlotTestFileName, false))
                {
                    using (var db = Doc.Database)
                    {
                        using (var tr = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
                        {
                            LayoutManager acLayoutMgr = LayoutManager.Current;
                            var plotSettings = db.PlotSettingsDictionaryId.GetObject(OpenMode.ForWrite) as DBDictionary;
                            DBDictionary lays = tr.GetObject(db.LayoutDictionaryId, OpenMode.ForWrite) as DBDictionary;
                            Layout layout = null;
                            foreach (DBDictionaryEntry item in lays)
                            {
                                if (item.Key.ToUpper() == "MODEL")
                                {
                                    ObjectId LayObjId = item.Value;
                                    layout = tr.GetObject(LayObjId, OpenMode.ForWrite) as Layout;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            if (layout == null)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("印刷するLayoutの取得に失敗！");
                                Doc.CloseAndDiscard();
                                return;
                            }
                            acLayoutMgr.CurrentLayout = layout.LayoutName;

                            PlotSettings plSet = GetPlotSettings(db, tr, plotSettings, layout);
                            var plSetvdr = PlotSettingsValidator.Current;

                            double DwgSc = db.Dimscale;
                            if (DwgSc == 0)
                            {
                                DwgSc = 1;
                            }

                            plSetvdr.RefreshLists(plSet);
                            plSetvdr.SetPlotConfigurationName(plSet, PlotListBox.SelectedItem.ToString(), "A4");
                            plSetvdr.SetPlotCentered(plSet, true);
                            plSetvdr.SetPlotType(plSet, GrxCAD.DatabaseServices.PlotType.Limits);
                            plSetvdr.SetPlotPaperUnits(plSet, PlotPaperUnit.Millimeters);
                            plSetvdr.SetCurrentStyleSheet(plSet, "縮小用.ctb");
                            plSet.PrintLineweights = true;
                            plSet.PlotPlotStyles = true;

                            Point2d PaperSz = plSet.PlotPaperSize;
                            double PaperWidth = PaperSz.X;
                            double PaperHeight = PaperSz.Y;
                            if (PaperWidth > PaperHeight)
                            {
                                plSetvdr.SetPlotRotation(plSet, PlotRotation.Degrees000);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                plSetvdr.SetPlotRotation(plSet, PlotRotation.Degrees270);
                            }
                            plSetvdr.SetUseStandardScale(layout, true);
                            plSetvdr.SetStdScaleType(plSet, StdScaleType.ScaleToFit);

                            layout.CopyFrom(plSet);

                            // 印刷
                            using (PlotInfo icPlInfo = new PlotInfo())
                            {
                                icPlInfo.Layout = layout.ObjectId;
                                icPlInfo.OverrideSettings = layout;
                                using (PlotInfoValidator icPlInfoVdr = new PlotInfoValidator())
                                {
                                    icPlInfoVdr.MediaMatchingPolicy = MatchingPolicy.MatchEnabled;
                                    icPlInfoVdr.Validate(icPlInfo);
                                    using (PlotEngine icPlEng = PlotFactory.CreatePublishEngine())
                                    {
                                        using (PlotProgressDialog icPlProgDlg = new PlotProgressDialog(false, 1, true))
                                        {
                                            icPlProgDlg.set_PlotMsgString(PlotMessageIndex.CancelJobButtonMessage, "Cancel Job");
                                            icPlProgDlg.set_PlotMsgString(PlotMessageIndex.CancelSheetButtonMessage, "Cancel Sheet");
                                            icPlProgDlg.set_PlotMsgString(PlotMessageIndex.SheetSetProgressCaption, "Sheet Set Progress");
                                            icPlProgDlg.set_PlotMsgString(PlotMessageIndex.SheetProgressCaption, "Sheet Progress");
                                            icPlProgDlg.LowerPlotProgressRange = 0;
                                            icPlProgDlg.UpperPlotProgressRange = 100;
                                            icPlProgDlg.PlotProgressPos = 0;
                                            icPlProgDlg.OnBeginPlot();
                                            icPlProgDlg.IsVisible = true;
                                            icPlEng.BeginPlot(icPlProgDlg, null);
                                            icPlEng.BeginDocument(icPlInfo, db.OriginalFileName, null, 1, false, "");
                                            icPlProgDlg.set_PlotMsgString(PlotMessageIndex.Status, "Plotting: " + db.OriginalFileName + " - " + layout.LayoutName);
                                            icPlProgDlg.OnBeginSheet();
                                            icPlProgDlg.LowerSheetProgressRange = 0;
                                            icPlProgDlg.UpperSheetProgressRange = 100;
                                            icPlProgDlg.SheetProgressPos = 0;
                                            icPlProgDlg.SheetProgressPos = 100;
                                            icPlProgDlg.OnEndSheet();
                                            icPlEng.EndDocument(null);
                                            icPlProgDlg.PlotProgressPos = 100;
                                            icPlProgDlg.OnEndPlot();
                                            icPlEng.EndPlot(null);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            if (PlotReactorErrChk == 2)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show(Doc.Name + "の印刷に成功！");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show(Doc.Name + "の印刷に失敗！");
                            }

                            tr.Commit();
                        }
                    }
                    Doc.CloseAndDiscard();
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        static public PlotSettings GetPlotSettings(Database idb, Transaction itr, DBDictionary iDic, Layout iLay)
        {
            PlotSettings plSet = default(PlotSettings);
            string strName = "PlotTest";
            if (iDic.Contains(strName))
            {
                plSet = iDic.GetAt(strName).GetObject(OpenMode.ForWrite) as PlotSettings;

            }
            else
            {
                plSet = new PlotSettings(iLay.ModelType);
                plSet.CopyFrom(iLay);
                plSet.PlotSettingsName = strName;
                plSet.AddToPlotSettingsDictionary(idb);
                itr.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(plSet, true);
            }
            return plSet;
        }

        public void PlotEventsRegister()
        {
            if (plotReactorMng != null)
            {
                plotReactorMng.BeginPlot += new BeginPlotEventHandler(PlotReactorMng_BeginPlot);
                plotReactorMng.EndPlot += new EndPlotEventHandler(PlotReactorMng_EndPlot);
                plotReactorMng.BeginDocument += new BeginDocumentEventHandler(PlotReactorMng_BeginDocument);
                plotReactorMng.EndDocument += new EndDocumentEventHandler(PlotReactorMng_EndDocument);
                plotReactorMng.BeginPage += new BeginPageEventHandler(PlotReactorMng_BeginPage);
                plotReactorMng.EndPage += new EndPageEventHandler(PlotReactorMng_EndPage);
                plotReactorMng.PlotCancelled += new PlotCancelledEventHandler(PlotReactorMng_PlotCancelled);
                plotReactorMng.PageCancelled += new PageCancelledEventHandler(PlotReactorMng_PageCancelled);
            }
        }

        public void PlotEventsUnRegister()
        {
            if (plotReactorMng != null)
            {
                plotReactorMng.BeginPlot -= new BeginPlotEventHandler(PlotReactorMng_BeginPlot);
                plotReactorMng.EndPlot -= new EndPlotEventHandler(PlotReactorMng_EndPlot);
                plotReactorMng.BeginDocument -= new BeginDocumentEventHandler(PlotReactorMng_BeginDocument);
                plotReactorMng.EndDocument -= new EndDocumentEventHandler(PlotReactorMng_EndDocument);
                plotReactorMng.BeginPage -= new BeginPageEventHandler(PlotReactorMng_BeginPage);
                plotReactorMng.EndPage -= new EndPageEventHandler(PlotReactorMng_EndPage);
                plotReactorMng.PlotCancelled -= new PlotCancelledEventHandler(PlotReactorMng_PlotCancelled);
                plotReactorMng.PageCancelled -= new PageCancelledEventHandler(PlotReactorMng_PageCancelled);
            }
        }
        void PlotReactorMng_BeginPlot(object sender, BeginPlotEventArgs e)
        {
        }
        void PlotReactorMng_EndPlot(object sender, EndPlotEventArgs e)
        {
        }
        void PlotReactorMng_PlotCancelled(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        void PlotReactorMng_PageCancelled(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        void PlotReactorMng_BeginDocument(object sender, BeginDocumentEventArgs e)
        {
            PlotReactorErrChk = 0;
        }
        void PlotReactorMng_BeginPage(object sender, BeginPageEventArgs e)
        {
            PlotReactorErrChk++;
        }
        void PlotReactorMng_EndPage(object sender, EndPageEventArgs e)
        {
            PlotReactorErrChk++;
        }
        void PlotReactorMng_EndDocument(object sender, EndDocumentEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void EndButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PlotEventsUnRegister();// イベントの解除
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

アプリケーションを終了したときにエラーが発生しているという事は、恐らくCAD本体に問題があると思いますので、一度メーカーに問い合わせてみてはいかがでしょうか。